# Unable to run ecj in Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa after installation

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler

I had pitched in installing `ecj` while I was in the phase of installing `Java` with `apt`. I had found `openjdk8` and few other variations along with this,- `ecj` as the option.

So I had tried installing `ecj`

```
anand@inc:~$ sudo apt install ecj
[sudo] password for anand:
```

I have been successfully installed it as well. Later I found out it is part of JDT - Java Developer Tools for Eclipse over the internet.

Now I have a problem executing `ecj`

```
anand@inc:~$ ecj
/usr/bin/ecj: 4: .: Can't open /usr/lib/java-wrappers/java-wrappers.sh
```

Can someone guide me, how I can run this `ecj`

Comment: `ecj` is just an alternative to the normal `javac` Java compiler. Unless you have a specific reason for using ecj it is normally better to stick with javac.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that. I am finding tag - `eclipse-cdt` in this ubuntu forum but I am not finding `eclipse-jdt` tag. And also I am not finding any `view` in `eclipse IDE` as well for `JDT`. Anyway I stand with you, as it is a one another alternative for java. **Now** I found description for `JDT` over this link,- https://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/ Thanks :)